# Any way to save a traceback object in Python

Tags: python, debugging, save, traceback

I was looking to possibly try and save a traceback object and somehow pickle it to a file that I can access.  An example of a use case for this is if I am submitting some python code to a farm computer to run and it fails,  it would be nice to be able to open a session and access that traceback to debug the problem rather than just seeing a log of the traceback.  I do not know if there is any sort of way to do this but thought it would be worth asking why it couldn't if so.

Answer (score 1):

okay so you can use `traceback.print_exception(type, value, traceback[, limit[, file]])` and save it in a text or json or you can refer to [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html)

if you find it helpful please mark it correct or upvote thanx..:)

Comment: OP doesn't want a log: "rather than just seeing a log of the traceback."  It sounds like you are talking about logging.  Please provide correct capitalization and punctuation for your answers.  (From [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "We don't expect every answer to be perfect, but answers with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get upvoted more frequently. Remember, you can always go back at any time and edit your answer to improve it.")

Comment: Correct.  Rather than getting a log of the error, it would be awesome to be able to somehow pickle the traceback object and save that object into a file that I can unpickle and retrieve the traceback state in a new session.  Similar to how pdb's post mortem pulls the sys.last_traceback traceback object and allows you to debug your session.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how you've written your code, the try statement is probably your best answer. Since any error is just a class that inherits Python's builtin `Exception`, you can raise custom errors everywhere you need more information about a thrown error. You just need to rename your errors or pass in an appropriate string as the first argument. If you then `try` your code and use the except statement `except CustomError as e`, you can pull all the information you want out of e in the except statement as a regular instance. Example:

Your code would be:

```
def script():
    try: codeblock
    except Exception as e: raise Error1('You hit %s error in the first block'% e)
    try: codeblock 2
    except Exception as e: raise Error2('You hit %s error in the second block' % e)

try: script()
except Exception as e:
    with open('path\to\file.txt','w') as outFile:
        outFile.write(e)
```

The last part is really nothing more than creating your own log file, but you have to write it down somewhere, right?

As for using the `traceback` module mentioned above, you can get error information out of that. Any of the commands here can get you a list of tracebacks:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html

On the otherhand, if you're trying to avoid looking at log files, the traceback module is only going to give you the same thing a log file would, in a different format. Adding your own error statements in your code gives you more information than a cryptic `ValueError` about what actually happened. If you print the traceback to your special error, it might give you still more information on your issue.

Comment: This code does not work, you'll get `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`